# Scala program - difficult to understand

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Can someone please explain the below code? I'm finding it very hard to understand. Also let me know if there is any better solution.

Update: I know basics like currying, pattern matching, List, map function. But I don't understand the need of using two generics A and B in flatMapSublists function, 'sublist @'. I think because of bits and pieces of lack of knowledge I could not understand the overall solution.

> > Finding all the values of nCr

```
//     Example:
//     scala> combinations(3, List('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f))
//     res0: List[List[Symbol]] = List(List('a, 'b, 'c), List('a, 'b, 'd), List('a, 'b, 'e), ...
```

Solution:

```
// flatMapSublists is like list.flatMap, but instead of passing each element
// to the function, it passes successive sublists of L.


def flatMapSublists[A, B](ls: List[A])(f: (List[A]) => List[B]): List[B] =
  ls match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case sublist @ (_ :: tail) => f(sublist) ::: flatMapSublists(tail)(f)
  }

  def ncr[A](n: Int, ls: List[A]): List[List[A]] =

    if (n == 0) List(Nil)
    else flatMapSublists(ls) { sl =>
      ncr(n - 1, sl.tail) map { sl.head :: _ }
  }

ncr(3, List('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f))
```

Output:

```
List(List('a, 'b, 'c), List('a, 'b, 'd), List('a, 'b, 'e), List('a, 'b, 'f), List('a, 'c, 'd), List('a, 'c, 'e), List('a,'c, 'f), List('a, 'd, 'e), List('a, 'd, 'f), List('a, 'e, 'f), List('b, 'c,'d), List('b, 'c, 'e), List('b, 'c, 'f), List('b, 'd, 'e), List('b, 'd, 'f), List('b, 'e, 'f), List('c, 'd, 'e), List('c, 'd, 'f), List('c, 'e, 'f), List('d, 'e, 'f))
```

Source: http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/p26.scala

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please provide details on your scala expertise, what parts of code do you undertsand/not understand. There are a lot of concepts applied here e.g. currying, pattern matching, anonymous functions, symbols. etc. Knowing what parts are confusing will help you get better response. Also, good to include the origin of the code e.g. This one looks to be a replica of http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/p26.scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regarding the generic types usage:**

acjay explained the general principle behind the usage of generics in flatmap. 
To give you some pointers on how to figure out the need for multiple types vs one, let's look at the input and output types of the two functions.

ncr: 
Input: List[A]
Output: List[List[A]]

flatmapLists: 
Input: 
List[A]
f: List[A] => List[B]

Output: 
List[B]

If we were to restrict the usage of the function flatMapSublists for functions f: which only support List[A] => List[List[A]], we could change the interface to use only one generic type and it would still work.

```
def flatMapSublists[A](ls: List[A])(f: (List[A]) => List[List[A]]): List[List[A]] =
```

**Regarding "sublist @"**

When ls is not Nil, sublist would be the same as ls, so you do not really need to specify it, you could very well use ls directly. So the updated function looks like this:

---

```
 def flatMapSublists[A](ls: List[A])(f: (List[A]) => List[List[A]]): List[List[A]] = {
   ls match {
     case Nil => Nil
     case (_ :: tail) => {
          f(ls) ::: flatMapSublists(tail)(f)
     }
   }
 }
```

---

**Alternate implementation**

following the traditional recursive approach (not tail-recursive though)

---

```
  def p26_ncr_recursive[A](n: Int, ls: List[A]): List[List[A]] = {
    if (n==0) List(Nil)
    else ls match {
      case Nil => Nil
      case head :: tail =>
        p26_ncr_recursive(n - 1, tail).map {
          head :: _
        } ::: p26_ncr_recursive(n, tail)
    }
  }
```

---

Answer (score 0):

> But I don't understand the need of using two generics A and B in flatMapSublists function, ...

All `flatMap`s and `map`s have two generics, one for the type of the List coming in, one for the type of the list going out. You might not be used to seeing both in one place because the standard library collections define those as methods with one type parameter on a pre-existing `List`, which defines the other type parameter at the `class` level.

> 'sublist @'

This syntax just defines a variable to be the entire matched pattern. You use this when the right side of the @ is not just a simple type match, but a pattern, and you want the whole value. You might think of the `@` as an assignment to a new `val` on the left hand side.

If you have other question, send a comment. The logic is kind of tricky, so I suggest trying to reason out the flow of things for a really simple case `ncr(3, List('a, 'b, 'c, 'd))`. You can litter the code with `println`s if that helps.